# Generate Gaussian and Uniform Random Variable

Tags: matlab

Hi guys i have one question. thanks for answers

Generate Gaussian and Uniform Random Variable by using rand, randn functions. plot probability density function and prove these variables are Uniform and Gaussian.

Comment: Sounds like "Do my homework"...

Comment: Uniform is pretty simple. Normal is a bit harder: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_distribution#Generating_values_from_normal_distribution

Comment: So, shervin, have you looked at my answer? Have you been able to correct it to its working form? If yes, please press the "edit" button below my answer and show me what you changed, I'll tell you whether it's correct or not.

Comment: Can you show me what you did by editing my answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally I'm not in the habit of answering questions that clearly prove you haven't tried *anything* yourself. Today is no different, but I'll do the following:

I'm gonna provide you with a little code, that contains a few intentional errors. It's up to you to figure out what the code does, and where the problems are.

Type `help <command>` or `doc <command>` in the Matlab command prompt to get more information on a specific command, for example:

```
>> help rand
```

will give you a wealth of information on the `rand` function. Now, without further ado:

```
%%# normal distribution

nvars = 1e6;

N = randn(nvars,1);

f = @(x) 1/sqrt(2*pi) * exp( -x^2 );

figure(1), clf, hold on

[n, x] = hist(N, 50);    
bar(x, n)

x = -10:10;
plot(x, f(x), 'r')



%%# uniform distribution

nvars = 1e6;

U = rand(nvars,1);

g = @(x) x>=0&x<=1;

figure(2), clf, hold on

[n, x] = hist(U, 2);
bar(x, n)

x = -1.5:1.5;
plot(x, g(x), 'r')
```

NOTE: After fixing the errors, it's up to you if you consider this "proof" or not. If I were a high school teacher, I might, but if I were a professor, I certainly wouldn't :)

Comment: "I'm gonna provide you with a little code, that contains a few intentional errors. It's up to you to figure out what the code does, and where the problems are." You just made my night :-)

Comment: -1: I understand what you intended to do here, I appreciate your willingness to help, and I disagree. SO is supposed to provide useful answers not only for the person who is asking, but for somebody else who comes across a similar problem and finds their way to the site. Having intentional errors is not going to be useful.

Comment: @Jonas: I agree, and I'll explain my full intention: to have the OP edit the code to its correct form once the question is accepted. If he fails to comply or correct properly, the answer is removed altogether and I cast a close vote.

Comment: @RodyOldenhuis: Fair enough. Once the answer is corrected, I'll be able to remove the downvote.